# Is there another way of solving $\frac{\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{a}{2}}$. Without the method of multiplying by the inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

So, with this: $$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{a}{2}}$$

I could just do $${\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}}\times{\frac{2}{a}}$$

But I was wondering if there was a way of simplifying the $\sqrt{a}$ with $a$ or the $\sqrt{2}$ and $2$.
I don't know, it seems there should exist a way of doing it. Another way of looking at a division of fractions, a more fundamental way, and using these similar expressions in the numerator and denominator to simplify it.

Comment: You could use negative exponents to augment the presentation, but the fundamentals behind what you are doing don't change... So you could write $\frac{\frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac a2}=\frac {a^{\frac 12}2^{-\frac 12}}{a\cdot2^{-1}}$...

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ , this gives the expression as , $\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @AmySkinner How? We have $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}$, on the numerator, not $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}$.                                    Please explain the process

Comment: @Manuel , multiplication is closed on $\mathbb{R}$ meaning that we can manipulate the product of $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}\times\frac{2}{a}$ as $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a}\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ which allows for this simplification, (this further extends to what was given in the answers below) as if you apply this to the process on $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ you will be left with the equation $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a}}$ which is simplified to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now. Thanks, your comment helped me more than any of the answers (mostly because the answers talked about using rational exponents, wich I haven't learned yet). But yeah, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac{a}{2}}=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{1/2}}{\frac{a}{2}}=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{1/2-1}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$$

First step:

$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/2}$$

Second step:

$$\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$$

Third step:

$$\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{1/2-1}=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{-1/2}=\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$$

Comment: Why is $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}=(\frac{a}{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$? How? (I haven't yet reached the chapter of fraction exponents, maybe that's why I don't understand. But why is it?)

Comment: @Manuel $\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}}$ for any positive numbers $x,y$

Comment: Check the edit @Manuel

Comment: Thanks for editing. Well, I don't know yet why $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=(\frac{a}{b})^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Though I haven't yet studied the properties of rational exponents yet so, that's what I'll do now. And after that, I'll re-read your answer. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @Manuel Think of it this way: If you know some properties of exponents, you know $a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}$. You also know $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}=a$. If $\sqrt{a}=a^m$ where $m$ is some number, the only way the property holds is if $m=1/2$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dfrac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt2}\times\dfrac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt 2}=\dfrac{a}{2}$, we have $\dfrac{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}\right)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt2}$. By taking reciprocals of both sides, we see that
$$
\dfrac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt a}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{a}}\, .
$$